# reusing one single button outside the form tags to submit two seperate forms using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit two forms with one button,

This is what i have right now

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" class="pclass">
<input type="text" name="name">
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" class="pclass">
<input type="text" name="name">
</form>

the button is here 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
```

trying to use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".pclass").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#form1, #form2").serialize();;

        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "proceed.php",
          data: formData
        }).done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

trying as above but not working, it sends empty form to the end page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's build a working snippet. Now we can see that the class `pclass` is on the inputs rather than the `button` you want.

```js
$(".pclass").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $("#form1, #form2").serialize();

  console.log(formData);
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proceed.php",
    data: formData
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" id="form1" class="~pclass">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="foo">
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" class="~pclass">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="bar">
</form>

the button is here
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pclass">Check</button> trying to use it like this
```